# I can't get properties of a Class using swift by class_copyPropertyList

Tags: ios, properties, swift

```
class func getPropertiesInfo() -> (propertiesName:[String], propertiesType:[String]) {
    var propertiesName:[String] = Array();
    var propertiesType:[String] = Array();

    var outCount:UInt32 = 0;
    var i:Int        = Int();

    var properties:UnsafePointer<objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(object_getClass(self), &outCount);
    println("\(outCount)");
}
```

I using:

```
    var infos = Model.getPropertiesInfo();
    println("names = \(infos.propertiesName)");
    println("types = \(infos.propertiesType)");
```

`Model` is my custom Class, has properties `name`(String) and `age`(int).

But i get nothing,

Comment: p.s. in a class function, `self` is the class it's called on. `object_getClass(self)` gets the metaclass. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your class subclasses from NSObject, or add @objc in front of your class name (which internally does the same I believe).

The class_copyPropertyList method will only work on NSObject subclasses, which Swift classes don't derive from.

Comment: It works! My error! object_getClass(AnyObject), this mother need AnyObject, but i pass a Class name to it, so it don't work!

Comment: "which internally does the same I believe" No it doesn't.

Comment: "The class_copyPropertyList method will only work on NSObject subclasses" Nope, the Objectice-C runtime works on all Objective-C classes. Also, you can even pass non-Objective-C Swift classes to Objective-C runtime functions and still get some information.

Comment: @newacct all Objective-C classes derive from NSObject in their class hierarchy

Comment: @SomeGuy: Absolutely not. You can define a root class at any time by not specifying a parent class. Even Cocoa comes with `NSProxy` and `Object` which are other root classes that do not derive from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 8):

**Swit 3 Version**

```
extension NSObject {

   // convert to dictionary
   func toDictionary(from classType: NSObject.Type) -> [String: Any] {

       var propertiesCount : CUnsignedInt = 0
       let propertiesInAClass = class_copyPropertyList(classType, &propertiesCount)
       var propertiesDictionary = [String:Any]()

       for i in 0 ..< Int(propertiesCount) {
          if let property = propertiesInAClass?[i],
             let strKey = NSString(utf8String: property_getName(property)) as String? {
               propertiesDictionary[strKey] = value(forKey: strKey)
          }
       }
       return propertiesDictionary
   }
}

// call this for NSObject subclass

let product = Product()
let dict = product.toDictionary(from: Product.self)
print(dict)
```